# PHP spl_autoload_register inheritance

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I have a page called house.php and a class in house.class.php. When I create an instace of that class in house.php it works. Now I want to make a chair.php file and a class Chair that extends House in house.class.php. Where should I put that class? spl_autoload_register doesn't find my class since its name isn't the same with the file. How can I improve function AutoloadClass ? Should I create a chair.class.php and use an require with house.class.php?

```
spl_autoload_register(null, false);
spl_autoload_extensions('.php, .class.php');
function AutoloadClass($class){
    $filename = $class.'.class.php';

    if (!file_exists($filename))
        {
            return false;
        }
        include $filename;
    }

spl_autoload_register('AutoloadClass');
```

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP spl\_autoload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899073/php-spl-autoload)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're calling `spl_autoload_extensions` you don't need to manually add `.class.php`. Further you can try calling `spl_autoload_register` with no arguments. It then work with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php which should work out of the box:

```
set_include_path(__DIR__);
spl_autoload_extensions('.php,.class.php');
spl_autoload_register();
```

`spl_autoload` will do the extension checking. Else you don't need `spl_autoload_extensions` and have to check for all extensions by yourself.

Another problem that you might face is that your class name is uppercase and your file name is lowercase. I would go with [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) standard so that class names and file names match. So don't add `.class.php`.

```
House -> House.php
Chair -> Chair.php
```