# Autoload namespaces based on directory structure

Tags: php, autoload, autoloader, spl-autoload-register

According to the top comment on the `PHP` page **[`spl_autoload_register( )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#92514)** :

> Good news for PHP 5.3 users with namespaced classes:
>
> When you create a subfolder structure matching the namespaces of the >containing classes, you will never even have to define an autoloader.

```
<?php
    spl_autoload_extensions(".php"); // comma-separated list
    spl_autoload_register();
?>
```

However, when I have the following structure:

`* classes/someclass.php`

`* index.php`

Where `someclass.php` contains the following:

```
<?php
    class someclass {
        function __construct( ) {
            echo 'It works!';
        }
    }
?>
```

and `index.php` contains:

```
<?php
    spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
    spl_autoload_register();

    new classes\someclass;
?>
```

Then I get the following error:

> Fatal error: spl_autoload(): Class classes\someclass could not be
>   loaded

Am I getting this wrong? How can I make this work?

*From the comments*

This doesn't work either for the class:

```
<?php
    namespace classes;
    class someclass {
        function __construct( ) {
            echo 'It works!';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899073/php-spl-autoload

Comment: @OhAuth Excuse me. I have absolutely _no_ idea how you can possibly _consider_ this a duplicate or even remotely related.

Comment: Is there  a namespace should be declared in someclass.php?

Comment: @cybersoft I tried that. Doesn't seem to work, unless like I said, i'm missing something.

Comment: `someclass` is *not* in the `classes` namespace. Namespaces are not the same as directories.

Comment: @SAz hmm... At least, first answer in the above link provides example of autoloading function

Comment: I wrote that comment on php.net some time ago when I was working on a Windows system. Later, I had to partially revoke what I wrote in that comment on the very same page in [another comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#111875), which also contains a possible solution to the problem that is the easiest I could think of (apart from using Composer).

Comment: @BhargavRao Why was the answer by SednaSoft deleted?

Comment: @SednaSoft - I reinstated your answer, but included the content of the link. Your answer may have been deleted as a link only answer.

Answer (score 5):

In your someclass.php file you must define the namespace at the begginning.

```
<?php 
namespace classes;
```

Answer (score 5):

TLDR; It works, but:

- `namespace classes;` is missing in `classes/someclass.php`
- `set_include_path(__DIR__);` is missing in `index.php`
- (`spl_autoload_extensions(".php")` is not necessary)

### Include Path

The [SPL autoload implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php) is include path based. Using a dot as include path is relative to the working directory (!) which is independent from script file location. `__DIR__` names the exact directory that is needed if the `classes` folder lies next to the `index.php` file as in the scenario.

### Directory Separator mapping

Next the autoloader implementation does map the class namespace separator properly on Unix systems. In case that got lost in the o/p, [the PHP source code clearly has this](https://lxr.room11.org/xref/php-src%407.1/ext/spl/php_spl.c#259).

### Case Sensitivity of File Names

What the source code also shows is that [file-names to load are made lowercase](https://lxr.room11.org/xref/php-src%407.1/ext/spl/php_spl.c#326). That is, if your file system is case sensitive, the file and directory names must be in lower case.

---

Refernces:

- https://lxr.room11.org/xref/php-src%407.1/ext/spl/php_spl.c#spl_autoload
- https://lxr.room11.org/xref/php-src%407.1/ext/spl/php_spl.c#307

---

- [PHP - most lightweight psr-0 compliant autoloader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12082507/367456)

Comment: The first two references are for PHP 7.

Answer (score 2):

The user, [SedaSoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8235685/sednasoft), who had posted the [Good news comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#92514) you which you refer, had subsequently posted [another comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#111875), due to a revision of ideas:

> What I said here previously is only true on Windows. The built-in
>   default autoloader that is registered when you call
>   `spl_autoload_register()` without any arguments simply adds the
>   qualified class name plus the registered file extension (`.php`) to each
>   of the include paths and tries to include that file.
>
> Example (on Windows):
>
> include paths:
>
> ```
> - "."
> - "d:/projects/phplib"
> ```
>
> qualified class name to load:
>
> ```
> network\http\rest\Resource
> ```
>
> Here's what happens:
>
> PHP tries to load
>
> ```
> '.\\network\\http\\rest\\Resource.php'
> -> file not found
> ```
>
> PHP tries to load
>
> ```
> 'd:/projects/phplib\\network\\http\\rest\\Resource.php'
> -> file found and included
> ```
>
> Note the slashes and backslashes in the file path. On Windows this
>   works perfectly, but on a Linux machine, the backslashes won't work
>   and additionally the file names are case-sensitive.
>
> That's why on Linux the quick-and-easy way would be to convert these
>   qualified class names to slashes and to lowercase and pass them to the
>   built-in autoloader like so:
>
> ```
> <?php
> spl_autoload_register(
>   function ($pClassName) {
>     spl_autoload(strtolower(str_replace("\\", "/", $pClassName)));
>   }
> );
> ?>
> ```
>
> But this means, you have to save all your classes with lowercase file
>   names. Otherwise, if you omit the strtolower call, you have to use the
>   class names exactly as specified by the file name, which can be
>   annoying for class names that are defined with non-straightforward
>   case like e. g. `XMLHttpRequest`.
>
> I prefer the lowercase approach, because it is easier to use and the
>   file name conversion can be done automatically on deploying.

---

Note that this commenter had actually posted an answer here on SO today, containing the above links (along with a short explantation), but it was subsequently deleted, whilst in the [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/16571525) - presumably due to its brevity. I have reinstated the commenter's answer, along with the content of the link. Their answer was as follows:

> I wrote that comment on php.net some time ago when I was working on a
>   Windows system. Later, I had to partially revoke what I wrote in that
>   comment on the very same page in another comment, which also contains
>   a possible solution to the problem that is the easiest I could think
>   of (apart from using Composer).

Here is a screenshot of the original answer:

[image: Original post]

Answer (score 2):

Do not roll your own autoloading, but use `composer` instead.

Create a `composer.json` in the root of your project:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "classes\\": "classes/"
        }
    }
}
```

Install `composer`, then run

```
 composer dump-autoload
```

In your `index.php`, require the autoloader:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

For reference, see

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading
- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/
- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: I roll my own just fine, just saying...  For example https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/blob/master/EVO/Autoloader.php

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix But why?

Comment: Why?  because I don't want my code depending on any third party systems.  That's one reason, another is my AutoLoader can register multiple namespace path pairs so I can re-base my namespace ( reset them to a top folder), and because I can.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix If you look closely at https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo, it already depends on at least seven 3rd-party systems. Take a look at http://wiki.c2.com/?WheelFactory and http://wiki.c2.com/?NotInventedHere. While it sure can be fun and an exercise to build these systems yourself, your efforts will be more wisely spend on something else.

Comment: what 3rd party systems? PHP? ha I mean frameworks ( as in code base ), anyway, I am a full time PHP senior developer and CIO, so I spend my normal time maintaining 4 websites and a custom B2B platform that runs on Rabbit, Sphinx and Mongo.  So ... yea... While it may be sad, coding stuff, is my idea of fun, I am married with late Teenage children after all.

Comment: Our company also uses a Amember, Wordpress, CI integration for most of our sites that run on CentOS, with a Full forward proxy DMZ, its SSAE-16/SOC3 compliant.  So I am well aware of "re-inventing" the wheel ( or not re-inventing it )  That doesn't mean you cant make a better wheel...

Comment: BTW @ArtisticPhoenix your link is not accessible anymore

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the spl_autoload_extensions () function if the files to load only have the php extension.
In my case, I create a class called autoload .. something similar to this:

```
<?php

class Autoload
{
    private static $_extensions = array(
        0 => '.inc',
        1 => '.lib.php',
        2 => '.class.php',
    );

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::set_include_path();
        spl_autoload_extensions(implode(',', self::$_extensions));
        spl_autoload_register(__CLASS__, 'load_class');
    }

    public static function set_include_paths()
    {
        set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
            realpath('classes');
            realpath('system');
            ...
            get_include_path();,
        )));
    }

    public function load_class($class)
    {
        if (!empty($class)) {
            spl_autoload($class);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The use of `?>` At the end of the file is not necessary.